# Quantify MCMC chain mixing

Tags: data-visualization, markov-chain-montecarlo

I'm running an MCMC process with several parallel chains (often hundreds).

To improve the visibility of the final plot, I only want to plot two chains per parameter: ideally the "best" and "worst" performing chains. I interpret this as the chain that shows the largest degree of mixing, and the one that shows the smallest.

Is this a reasonable approach? If so, how should I quantify the mixing of a chain to pick the "best" and "worst" ones?

Comment: Are all these chains sampling from the same posterior distribution, or is there some variation (e.g. different hyperparameters, tempering...)?

Comment: I actually use a parallel-tempered code, but I'm only plotting the cold chain for my actual parameters (not using any hyperparameters) .

Comment: In that case, wouldn't it make sense to plot the cold chain and the hottest chain?

Comment: No because *each temperature* used consists of of multiple chains. Furthermore, I am not interested in the hot chains and I'm after some method that can be generalized to non-parallel tempered methods.